# Unused static (char *) variable "rscid" / "sccsid" in source code?

Tags: c

I was looking through the source code of the PHP interpreter and found this piece of code :

**Why is there a static char * variable defined but not used?** I'm sure there has to be a reason for that, but with the data I have, I don't get it :-/

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/strlcat.c

It seems to be the case on a lot of C files, here is another:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/rindex.c?txt

Comment: It stands for "resource ID" or "RCS ID" and it identifies the file and the version. [link](http://ikiwiki.info/todo/meta_rcsid/).

Comment: But why a static variable? Does the .c file get included somewhere else? I'm not quite sure I understand this. In addition, the content of the variable is also there as a comment, line 25 in the PHP src file.

Comment: static so it can't cause linker errors (other files have identically named variables as well).

Comment: @H2CO3: No, it doesn't stand for "resource ID", it's just RCS (Revision Control System) ID. "rcs" wouldn't be an abbreviation for "resource"; the letters are in the wrong order.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yup, noticed that (but I *have* seen it being interpreted as "resource ID"!), but it was too late to edit...

Comment: For quite a long time now, GCC has removed such unused variables from the binary, so the way to get it into the binary is to make it externally visible, which means the name needs to be unique.  It's a nuisance, though since DVCS like Git do not support version tagging as easily, it is becoming less of an issue — you can't reliably embed the information into the files in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From wikipedia ([Source Code Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System))

> SCCS is also known for the sccsid string, for example:
>
> ```
> static char sccsid[] = "@(#)ls.c        8.1 (Berkeley) 6/11/93";
> ```
>
> This string contains the file name, date, and can also contain a comment. After compilation, this string can be found in binary and object files by looking for the pattern "@(#)" and can be used determine which source code files were used during compilation.

Note that RCS evolved from SCCS.

Comment: I'm not sure it *evolved* from it, but RCS was pretty much intended as a *replacement* for SCCS.